# How to safely pass a C++ string to Rust?

Tags: c++, rust

I have this Rust function:

```
pub extern "C" fn do_something(my_string: &str) {
    let s = String::from(my_string);
}
```

That I call on C++ with this:

```
std::string my_string("hello");
do_something(my_string.c_str());
```

Signature:

```
extern "C" void* do_something(const char*);
```

I get this error right on the `String::from` line:

```
memory allocation of 127963177044160 bytes failedAborted (core dumped)
```

I guess that it's because the string passed has no `\n` so it tries to make a string of the maximum size possible.

How to safely pass a `std::string` to Rust?

Comment: The title asks for a *"C++ string"*, but you aren't passing a C++ `std::string`. You can call `do_something` without a `std::string`, like `do_something("hello");`. That really makes it a [tag:C] question. This is an important difference when it comes to Rust's FFI. If you do want to interface with C++, have a look at the [cxx](https://crates.io/crates/cxx) crate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> That I call on C++ with this:
>
> ```
> do_something(my_string.c_str());
> ```

So on the C++ side you're calling a function with a *C string* as input (not an `std::string`, which is a very relevant distinction).

This means the Rust function should take a C string as input, which `&str` definitely isn't.

Thus `do_something` should be declared as:

```py
pub extern "C" fn do_something(my_string: *const c_char) {
```

following which as Jmb notes you may want to use [`CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html) in order to safely wrap the pointer.

Answer (score 6):

The `&str` type is not FFI-safe. I would expect the Rust compiler to issue a warning to that effect. Rust slices consist of a pointer and a length and do not have a layout compatible with the C++ `const char*`.

One option would be to have `do_something` accept a pointer and a length (`*const u8` and `usize`, respectively), call `std::slice::from_raw_parts` to exchange those for a `&'a [u8]`, and call `std::str::from_utf8_unchecked` to exchange that for a `&str`. You must ensure the safety conditions documented along with each of those functions are upheld, including that the string contains valid UTF-8.

Comment: Or use [`CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html) which is intended precisely for this use case.